# Dress-up game programming

Tags: flash

This is my reference dress-up game website.
http://www.dressupgirl.net/dressup/1552/Christmas-is-Here.html
Anyone can tell me that is this game using the Actionscripts 3.0 or 2.0?
How to make the scrolling button and drag out the clothes inside the scrolling bar location?(is it need to use the actionscripts 3.0 or 2.0,which coding should i write)?

Answer (score 1):

The application is quite simple and could be done either with AS2 or AS3 (or even javascript although you may do it with more ease in flash if you're a newbie).

You will mainly need to explore [MouseEvents](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) to select and drag MovieClips. There's a lot of existing examples related to [drag and drop](http://www.google.com/search?q=actionscript+3+drag+and+drop) already.

Do some research and see how far you can get on your own. You may get back here and ask more problem specific questions once you've got this started.

Answer (score 1):

To find out what language the Flash game was written in, grab a copy of trial version of Sothink Flash Decompiler use it to peek at the source of the swf, which you can get from your browser's cache. A quick look at the code will help you determine what version of Actionscript was used in that particular flash project.

Answer (score 0):

Theo T. is correct. Look into the Mouse Event area of Actionscript.

(I will add that from personal experience, AS2 is more like Javascript than AS3, but AS3 makes a lot of sense once you've learned it. )

To find out what language the Flash game was written in, grab a copy of trial version of Sothink Flash Decompiler use it to peek at the source of the swf, which you can get from your browser's cache. A quick look at the code will help you determine what version of Actionscript was used in that particular flash project.

**You should ask permission from the author of the game before decompiling it, though. *Decompiling other people's work without proper permission is illegal in many places and can get you into serious trouble.***